# Maintaining order when requesting AVAssets

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch, photosframework

I am attempting to build a video merging app that allows users to select several short clips from a collection view and then generates a preview of the videos all merged into one. I am using the Photos framework (PHCachingImageManager) to populate the collection view and am passing an array of the selected PHAssets to the function below in order to request low quality AVAssets (for merging & generating the preview).

The problem is, I need to keep the AVAssets in the order in which the user selected them, but the "requestAVAsset" function is asynchronous and the completion handler is often called multiple times. I've never used Dispatch Groups before, but attempted to use them below...and the AVAssets are still out of order sometimes.

```
func requestAVAssets(assets: [PHAsset]) -> [AVAsset] {
    var videoArray: [AVAsset] = []
    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
    let videoOptions = PHVideoRequestOptions()
    videoOptions.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true
    videoOptions.deliveryMode = .fastFormat
    for asset in assets {
        dispatchGroup.enter()
        self.imageManager.requestAVAsset(forVideo: asset, options: videoOptions, resultHandler: { (video, audioMix, info) in
            guard video != nil else { return }
            videoArray.append(video!)
            dispatchGroup.leave()
        })
    }
    dispatchGroup.wait()
    return videoArray
}
```

I'm guessing I've either misplaced some code or am approaching this in entirely the wrong way! Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you capture the current index while you're iterating the AVAssets, you can insert rather than append. That's how I do it, at least.

```
func requestAVAssets(assets: [PHAsset]) -> [AVAsset] {
    var videoArray = [AVAsset?](repeating: nil, count: assets.count)
    let videoOptions = PHVideoRequestOptions()
    videoOptions.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true
    videoOptions.deliveryMode = .fastFormat
    for (i, asset) in assets.enumerated() {
        self.imageManager.requestAVAsset(forVideo: asset, options: videoOptions, resultHandler: { (video, audioMix, info) in
            guard let video = video else { return }
            videoArray.remove(at: i)
            videoArray.insert(video, at: i)
        })
    }
    return videoArray.flatMap { $0 }
}
```

Giving the array the desired number of items as `nil` will stop it from erroring when inserting items, and then when the download is complete, remove the existing nil value and replace it with the actual `AVAsset`.

Finally, flatMap the resulting array to unpack the optionals (and optionally check that you have the desired number of items by comparing it with the incoming `assets` array).

Comment: Thanks Daniel, this worked like a charm. I think you meant for "videoArray[I] = video" to be "videoArray.insert(video, at: i)" though, since otherwise you'll get an array index out of bounds error. I was unaware of the flat mapping shortcut for unpacking optionals too! :)

Comment: That'll teach me for writing code without the static analyser! You'll also still need your `DispatchGroup` or a `DispatchSemaphore` to wait for all the requests to finish before returning from the function (but I'm sure you figured that out).

Answer (score 1):

Dodging the dispatch question entirely because it's late and I've had a bad day, but what if you kept the "correct" index associated with the video, and then sorted on that? I think something like this would work.

```
struct SelectedVideo {
    let index: Int
    let asset: AVAsset
}

func requestAVAssets(assets: [PHAsset]) -> [AVAsset] {
    var videoArray: [SelectedVideo] = []
    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
    let videoOptions = PHVideoRequestOptions()
    videoOptions.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true
    videoOptions.deliveryMode = .fastFormat
    for (index, asset) in assets.enumerated() {
        dispatchGroup.enter()
        self.imageManager.requestAVAsset(forVideo: asset, options: videoOptions, resultHandler: { (videoMb, audioMixMb, infoMb) in
            guard let video = videoMb else return
            videoArray.append(SelectedVideo(index, video))
            dispatchGroup.leave()
        })
    }
    dispatchGroup.wait()
    return videoArray.sort { $0.index < $1.index}.map({$0.video})
}
```

This is kind of a hack (haven't even tried compiling it), but like I said, it's been a bad day.

A couple minor changes to note: I changed the params to the closure to say "Mb" which means "maybe" and is a nice convention I've seen for naming optionals passed to closures. Also, instead of "guard video != nil" followed by force-unwrapping, it's much preferred to do a "guard let video = videoMb", and then video is non-optional.

Comment: I read Daniel's answer below first, but I'm pretty sure this would also work, so thanks! I like the tip for the "Mb" naming convention and for avoiding force-unwrapping.